# More Detailed Explanation on Michael Hartl's Tutorial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In Michael Hartl's tutorial, it is written

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

it becomes

```
<label for="user_name">Name</label>
<input id="user_name" name="user[name]" type="text" />
```

and

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email %>
```

becomes

```
<label for="user_email">Email</label>
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" />
```

Was looking it for so long but I really could not understand how the code can translate to html. Can anyone explain?

These are all enclosed in the following code

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 .
 .
 .
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's handled by [`erb`](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/) preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `label`, `<%= f.label :email %>` is really just a method-call: You call `form.label(:email)`. The `<%=` is short for `<% print`.

These methods are form-helpers, and included in the form object from [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

If you look at the code in [the label method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a306b3498bfacf1ddc995838b91121a9641a07ca/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L765) you'll see it instantiates a `Tags::Label` object.

Looking deeper at that [`Tags::Label`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0b7edd4418bcca97d517070d8578684a11897b8f/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/label.rb) it does a lot, but the most important part is the call to [`label_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e0e9d5bd8600c01de6b73487bf66046d179c0ed7/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L207). Which renders a label tag.

The contents of the label tag is changed from `:email` to `Email` by using the [`humanize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) helper. (We ignore all the localisation and translation for now). You can use these helpers everywhere yourself. Open a console with `rails console`:

```
:email.to_s.humanize #=> "Email"
:postal_code.to_s.humanize #=> "Postal code"
```

In rails most of these stacks are hard to follow, because it is both abstracted into models (to allow re-use) and a lot of edge-cases such as localisation or XSS security mix in a lot of additional "cruft" that makes the path the code follows harder to understand.

But, in short, `<%= f.label(:email) %>` could roughly be translated to `print label_tag(:email.to_s.humanize, id: :email)`.

Comment: Really really helpful explanation and resources provided. Am still a ruby on rails beginner. I appreciate it! :) I just realised how much more I need to catch up to be better every day.

Comment: If this answers your question, can you mark it as such? Otherwise: can you provide some additional questions so we can answer it?